# Add animation to SKSpriteNode on touch (Swift)

Tags: swift, animation, touch, skspritenode

I have a scene with lots of squares (`SKSpriteNode`) in it.

I can detect which node has tapped but I want to add an animation (like a change color or fade color or glow) to it, after the node was touched.

What can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` method.

You can use an [`SKAction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/) on it. For example to change the color, you can do it like that:

```
//in your touchesBegan-method
yourNode.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: duration)


//in your touchesEnded-method
yourNode.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: duration)
```

This will change the color of the node to blue during the touch and change it to green, when the node isn't being touched anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want a complete answer

Comment: What do you mean with complete answer? That is the answer to your asked question.

Comment: when touch down, the color change and on touch up back to first color. like a button.

Comment: Then you have to add that information to your question.

Comment: yes i must add. thanks for your answer. i'll accept your answer tomorrow. (i wait just for a better answer)

Comment: I've accepted your answer. can you please show me how can i change color after a duration?